# Binding to SelectList generates error of no proper with name ID even though the entity contains said property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am binding 4 `SelectList` in my controller and when I pull up the page where the `Drop Down Lists` are rendered I am presented with the error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Boolean' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

but there is an `ID` property in the entity it is pulling from so I am not sure what is going wrong.

Code Error is popping on:

```
model.Sections = new SelectList(db.Sections.Select(s => s.ID > 0), "ID", "Name").ToList();
```

And here is the entire `Section` definition and as you can see there is a property named `ID`

```
public class Section
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int16 ID { get; set; }

    public Int64? LogoFileID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string RouteName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
    public virtual File Logo { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the call in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSection, Model.Sections)
```

And the property from the ViewModel:

```
[DisplayName("Original Release Name")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Sections { get; set; }
public Int16 SelectedSection { get; set; }
```

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong since `Section` does contain `ID`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you show more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.Sections.Select(s => s.ID > 0)`

This means select the RESULT of s.ID > 0 -- so you're getting a `IEnumerable<bool>` as a result.  Perhaps what you meant was `db.Sections.Where(s => s.ID > 0)` -- this will return a list of Sections where ID > 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I am still trying to learn the fluent API for LINQ. Converting from `Select` to `Where` made it work perfectly.